# Optimise turbolinks for screen readers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, accessibility, turbolinks

Is there a way to make [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues) notify screen readers automatically that the title and the body of the document changed?

Otherwise, turbolinks makes any otherwise accessible website pretty cumbersome to use with a screenreader.

**Update**

I opened a [related issue](https://github.com/techvision/waiable/issues/22) at [Waiable gem](https://github.com/techvision/waiable), a gem that targets on making Rails accessible.

Comment: Have you looked at [ARIA Live Regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions)?

Comment: I know Live Regions, and I read somewhere a little bit about a related issue, where the statement was that Live Regions seem not to be meant to be used for full website contents. But I'm not familiar enough with this topic.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @steveax is correct. You should use ARIA live regions. You should probably tie into the events system of turbolinks to do announcements.

```
jQuery(document).on("ready page:change", function () {
    // do ARIA live stuff in here, e.g. using a11yfy
    jQuery.a11yfy.assertiveAnnounce(document.title);
});
```

Here is a jQuery implementation of ARIA-live https://github.com/dylanb/a11yfy/blob/master/a11yfy/jquery.a11yfy.core.js#L464
Here is an Angular.js implementation (which is more robust) https://github.com/dequelabs/ngA11y/blob/master/src/nga11yannounce.js

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. What about the page title? It won't be read automatically (as this happens whenever the page refreshes fully).

Comment: Using ARIA live, as implemented by the above libraries, you can announce any amount of text - including the page title. So you would update the page title and announce the text at the same time. The real issue here is that you do whatever makes sense for the contextual change. Sometimes that might not be announcing the title.

Comment: Sounds legitimate. I'm waiting for some more possible input for a while, and then likely will choose your answer as correct.

Comment: just updated the answer to give specifics on how you might do it